# Do not see module imports at top level of Python package

Tags: python

Consider the following `python` package structure

```
 working_directory/
-- test_run.py
-- mypackge/
---- __init__.py
---- file1.py
---- file2.py
```

and say inside `file1.py` I have defined a function, `func1()` and I've also imported some functions from numpy with something like `from numpy import array`. Now I want to import and use `mypackage` from `test_run.py` without seeing these numpy functions in the namespace. I want to import it using `import mypackage as mp` and see

```
mp.file1.func1()
mp.file2.func2()
etc
```

I don't want to see `mp.file1.array()`. How can I do it?

Comment: You can't without deleting it, but then the functions in `file1` won't be able to access it. I have a feeling this is an XY problem. Why do you want to do this?

Comment: You can not do this directly.  If you want to manage the namespace that closely, you will need a stub file at `file1`, that just imports things you need from `file1x`, where `filex` is your current file1, renamed.

Comment: If you don't want to see `mp.file1.array()`, the correct solution is to not look for it in the first place.

Comment: Well, I would like to make my functions available in an organized form from 'mypackage', and if I need to use some software to implement them I don't want this to be accessible from the outside, because it's unnecessary... Is that wrong?

Comment: In principle you are not wrong. However I think this is a battle that is not worth fighting... You could consider making is as clean as possible by using `import numpy as np` and the `np.array`. Also, wouldn't you expect the user to look only for functions that you explain in the documentation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possibility would be to use underscores:

```
from numpy import array as _array.
```

Although this doesn't prohibit people from accessing `mp.file1._array` it is a general considered that variables beginning with underscores are 'private'.

AFAIK, there is no simple way to disallow access to any variable in python. (one way would be to make it properties of a class, see: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property)